# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.19.0 or one of its dependencies

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, mysql.data

I have just installed the latest version of `MySQL.Data.EntityFramework Version 8.0.19`.

The first time I run the code I got the following error:

> The latest nuget package (MySql.Data 8.0.19) contains an unsigned
>   version of Ubiety.Dns.Core.dll. This results in an exception while
>   loading.

according to: [this bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98204), I need to install: [Ubiety.Dns.Core/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ubiety.Dns.Core/) package... so I installed this package. Now I am getting the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFramework,
>   Version=8.0.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or
>   one of its dependencies.

---

As a workaround I tried to install the previous version, `MySQL.Data.EntityFramework Version 8.0.18` but I cannot find any previous version: [MySql.Data.EntityFramework Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework/).

Anyone knows if the previous versions have been removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who do not want the thousands of redundant warnings that for some reason appears with Ubiety.Dns.Core -- installing an earlier version worked fine for me:

```
Install-Package Ubiety.Dns.Core -Version 2.4.1
```

Answer (score 2):

check your Web.Config if you have this rows.

```
     <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data,      Version=8.0.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

and also added provider:

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
```

Answer (score 2):

### Update:

`MySQL.Data 8.0.19` has a dependency on [Ubiety.Dns.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ubiety.Dns.Core/), which is not automatically installed. You need to install **Ubiety.Dns.Core** separately after installing `MySQL.Data 8.0.19`

Also note that Oracle has removed all the previous versions of `MySQL.Data 8.0.19`, [see here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework/) so if you upgrade to 8.0.19 you cannot go back to 8.0.18... I believe the reason for removing all the previous versions is that they had a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274136/connectionstring-for-connecting-3-master-nodes-to-mysql) with multi-host connection string which was fixed in 8.0.19.

---

### Original answer:

In my case, the reason I was getting an error was that I had forgotten to upgrade all of the projects in my solution to `MySQL.Data 8.0.19` and some of them  were still on `8.0.18`.

Answer (score 2):

wow, amazingly, I am having the exact same issue.  What I did to resolve:

- Update all projects to 8.0.19 of the mysql provider.
- Re-add the db provider tag to my web.config.  I had accidently removed it.  That was my fault.
- Finally, I installed the Ubiety.Dns.Core.

Doing all of this resolved my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Currently I've resorted to using 8.0.18 until a fix is released, since installing Ubiety.Dns.Core in my projects results in thousands of warnings across my source code.

```
Install-Package MySql.Data -version 8.0.18
```

Answer (score 0):

for me removing following part of code was the fix

```
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
           <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```